# How is it possible to change default labels in Material Paginator?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using Material Paginator to paginate my table. My application has RTL style. I need to change the default mat paginator labels (to another language). How is it possible? Can I customize the labels?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the component you are using material paginator in, add this to .component.ts file

```js
import { MatPaginatorIntl } from '@angular/material/paginator';

export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private paginator: MatPaginatorIntl) {
    paginator.itemsPerPageLabel = "My Items Per Page";
    paginator.firstPageLabel = "First Page Label";
    paginator.nextPageLabel = "My Next Page";
    paginator.previousPageLabel = "My Previous Page";
    paginator.getRangeLabel = (page: number, pageSize: number, length: number) => {
      length = Math.max(length, 0);
      const startIndex = page * pageSize;
      const endIndex =
        startIndex < length
          ? Math.min(startIndex + pageSize, length)
          : startIndex + pageSize;
      return `${startIndex + 1} of ${endIndex} / ${length}`;
    }
  }
  // ...
}
```

See https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/api#material-paginator-services

Comment: I created `CustomMatPaginatorIntl.ts` file and added your codes. There are some errors in `import { MatPaginatorIntl } from '@angular/material';` , `itemsPerPageLabel` and `nextPageLabel`, `previousPageLabel` and `this.changes.next();`

Comment: I have a StackBlitz and it is working, Can you tell which errors

Comment: @Arijit Tiwari, `import { MatPaginatorIntl } from '@angular/material';` has the following error: `Module '"@angular/material"' has no exported member 'MatPaginatorIntl'.` and also, `Property 'itemsPerPageLabel' does not exist on type 'CustomMatPaginatorIntl'.` for `this.itemsPerPageLabel`.

Comment: I'm using latest Angular and Material (v 15.1). Can you please give me a link to study your code on StackBlitz?

Comment: It's currently in angular 7 https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vqbvpq-vgfmec

Comment: Is it possible to change `of` in `1 - 10 of 100` to something else?

Comment: @AlexWright Yer, And I have updated answer